how are fix react native metro config
Error: While trying to resolve module @react-native/metro-config from file E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\metro.config.js, the package E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\package.json was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a main module field that could not be resolved (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\index. Indeed, none of these files exist:
 E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\index(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
   E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\@react-native\metro-config\index\index(.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:243:17)
    at E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at async Promise.all (index 8)
    at async visit (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 19)
    at async visit (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async visit (E:\mvscommerce\mvsshop\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.

npm i metro-config --save-dev
